# How to add e2e test to the existing repo using NX?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, cypress, nrwl-nx

In the tutorial video, I can see that when he created a new project NX also create a sibling repo for e2e test cases.

https://nx.dev/react-tutorial/01-create-application

My question is that I got a monorepo which I already created, which have a structure like this. front end was created with `npx-create-react-app ...`

```
MyApp
 - FrontEndRepo
 - BackEndRepo
```

According to NX convention [Why does nrwl nx create a separate e2e project for each app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763075/why-does-nrwl-nx-create-a-separate-e2e-project-for-each-app)

If I start creating my project with it should be something like this.

```
MyApp
     - FrontEndRepo
     - FrontEndRepo-e2e
     - BackEndRepo
     - BackEndRepo-e2e
```

So how can I add those e2e test folders to existing repo?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to just create a project structure in each `-e2e` folder and install Cypress in both places.

To run front-end or back-end tests from the root, add two scripts in `package.json`, changing the config file reference in each one.

The `cypress.config.js` in each `-e2e` folder is specific to the requirements of that project, e.g API url etc.

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test:fe": "cypress open --config-file FrontEndRepo-e2e/cypress.config.js",
    "test:be": "cypress open --config-file BackEndRepo-e2e/cypress.config.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Nx to generate it for you:

`npx nx generate @nrwl/cypress:cypress-project FrontEndRepo-e2e --project=FrontEndRepo`